# I want to know what is the difference between all output in this code?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to know what is the difference between all output? Why are there four different outputs?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3};
    int*ptr=arr;
    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %p\t %d \n",arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],ptr,*ptr);
    *ptr++=-1;
    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %p\t %d \n",arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],ptr,*ptr);
     *++ptr=-2;
    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %p\t %d \n",arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],ptr,*ptr);
    (*ptr)++;
    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %p\t %d \n",arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],ptr,*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output

```
 1   2   3   0x7ffe27496054  1 
-1   2   3   0x7ffe27496058  2 
-1   2   -2  0x7ffe2749605c  -2 
-1   2   -1  0x7ffe2749605c  -1
```

Comment: `*ptr++=-1;` why do things like that? It just makes it hard for people to read, understand and maintain the code.

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: 1  2  3  0x7ffe27496054  1 ---------------------------------------------
-1  2  3  0x7ffe27496058  2 ---------------------------------------------
-1  2  -2  0x7ffe2749605c  -2--------------------------------------------- 
-1  2  -1  0x7ffe2749605c  -1

Comment: @sarahamdy, It would be better if you add this to the question itself, not in a comment.

Comment: @sarahamdy Please [edit] your question to include actual and expected output. And show it by *copy-pasting* and not rewriting (as rewriting could add unrelated typos and errors).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, mixing the `++` operators with other operators in the same expression is almost always a bad thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude@anastaciua  ok i edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok lets start. 
Pointer stores memory address and giving a star(*) before a pointer variable denotes the value of that memory address.

```
int*ptr=arr;
```

In the above line you have copied the address of first index of the array(arr) into the ptr pointer.
So for the first print the pointer ptr value is the address of the first index of the array that means arr[0].

Then the second line:

```
*ptr++=-1;
```

Here you are post incrementing the value of ptr first, as ptr represents the address of the first index of the arr, so it will represent the address of second index of the array(arr[1]) in the next statement. but as it post incremented while setting the value -1 it would be set to array position 0(arr[0]).

Then the below line:

```
*++ptr=-2;
```

Here you are pre incrementing the value of ptr, so it would indicate the address of 3rd index of the array(arr[2]) and thus will set the value of arr[2] to -2.

Then the following line:

```
(*ptr)++;
```

Here you are incrementing the value of the address of ptr, as at that moment ptr is indicating the value of arr[2], so it will increment the value of arr[2] by 1.

Let me know if you don't understand any part. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
*ptr++ = -1;
```

is equivalent to

```
*ptr = -1;
ptr += 1;
```

And

```
*++ptr = -2;
```

is equivalent to

```
ptr += 1;
*ptr = -2;
```

Both of these should be quite easy to infer from your output.

Lastly

```
(*ptr)++;
```

which is equivalent to

```
*ptr += 1;
```

which increases what `ptr` is pointing to, but not `ptr` itself.

Comment: i think the last one of your answer is wrong as (*ptr)++ doesn't equal to (*ptr++) as the two brackets have the high priority so (*ptr) means the value which pointer points to it then ++ means increment this value

Comment: Surely `(*ptr)++` increments the thing pointed to by `ptr`, but `*ptr++` reads the thing pointed to by `ptr` and post increments `ptr` ?

Answer (score 0):

## In the first line int*ptr=arr; means creating pointer to intger which hold the address of the first element array as arr=arr[0] so when print (ptr) will be the address of arr[0] and when print (*ptr) will print the value of the arr[0] which equle one

```
*ptr++=-1;
```

## this line include post increment so firstly the value of arr[0] will be -1 then pointer will be incremented to include the address of arr[1] so when print arr[0] will be -1 ,,print (ptr) will be the address of the second element arr[1] and (*ptr) will print the value of arr[1] which is 2

```
 *++ptr=-2;
```

## this line include pre increment so firstly pointer will be incremented to include the address of arr[2] then  the value of arr[2] will be -2 so when print arr[2] will be -2 ,,print (ptr) will be the address of the third element arr[2] and (*ptr) will print the value of arr[2] which is -2

finally

```
 (*ptr)++;
```

this line will increment the value which pointer points to it as () has a high priority so (*ptr) means the value that pointer points to it and ++ will increment this value